# "invalid literal for int() with base 10:'username'"

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am making a web app with Django 1.7,python 2, but I am stuck in a part where I need that anonymous users can see the profiles of registered users (The URL is like this: "www.website.com/username) but I keep getting this error:

> "invalid literal for int() with base 10:'andyjrr'"

where "andyjrr' is an username I pass it via URL.

This is my views.py:

```
def profiles(request, username):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    person = UserProfile.objects.get(user=username)

    return render_to_response('detail.html',{'person':person},context)
```

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,null=True,blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)

    about_me = models.TextField(max_length=100,default='',blank=True)
    experience = models.TextField(max_length=250,default='',blank=True)
    offers = models.TextField(max_length=110,default='',blank=True)
```

TRACEBACK:

> /home/andyjrr/Documents/jobby/users/views.py in profiles
>
> ```
>   person = UserProfile.objects.get(user=username)
> ```

Comment: Are you sure that the `user` field in `UserProfile` is a string, and not an int or a ForeignKey?

Comment: in the model I have it like this user = models.OneToOneField(User,null=True,blank=True), but if I try user_username or user.username it gives an error where I have to xhoose beetween user, user_id and the other fields int the model, I will edit now and put the model in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the user field in the UserProfile model is a ForeignKey/OneToOne to auth.User.

If it is, then you'll need to modify your filter to join on the actually username of the auth.User model.

```
person = UserProfile.objects.get(user__username=username)
```